# My if else statement doesn't seems to work. How do I prevent sending empty data to the Database?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, visual-studio-2010, if-statement

```
 private void btnSubmitConsultation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int medicalHistoryResult = insertMedicalHistory();

        if (medicalHistoryResult > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Document(s) submitted", "Success");
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Insert Fail");
        }


        int allergiesResult = insertAllergies();

        if (allergiesResult > 0)
        {
            if (txtNewAllergy.Text != null || txtReactions.Text != null)
            {
                if (txtNewAllergy.Text == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please key in the Type of the allergy", "WARNING");
                }
                else if (txtReactions.Text == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please key in the Description of the allergy", "WARNING");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Submitted, fool");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not submitted, fool");
        }


    }
```

Well the medicalHistoryResult seems to work fine, but the allergiesResult isn't doing anything at all.

My insertAllergies function is just a normal INSERT, nothing fancy.

This is my insertAllergies function:

```
private int insertAllergies()
    {
        int allergiesResult = 0;

        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

        try
        {
            string strPatient = "SELECT patientID FROM PATIENT WHERE patientID=@searchPatientID";
            SqlCommand cmdPatient = new SqlCommand(strPatient, connection);
            cmdPatient.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchPatientID", txtPatientID.Text);

            string strAllergies = "INSERT ALLERGIES (allergyType, allergyDesc, patientID) " +
                "VALUES (@insertType, @insertDesc, @insertPatient)";
            SqlCommand cmdAllergies = new SqlCommand(strAllergies, connection);

            connection.Open();

            cmdAllergies.Parameters.AddWithValue("@insertType", txtNewAllergy.Text);
            cmdAllergies.Parameters.AddWithValue("@insertDesc", txtReactions.Text);

            SqlDataReader readPatient = cmdPatient.ExecuteReader();
            if (readPatient.Read())
            {
                string addPatient = readPatient["patientID"].ToString();
                cmdAllergies.Parameters.AddWithValue("@insertPatient", addPatient);
            }
            readPatient.Close();

            allergiesResult = cmdAllergies.ExecuteNonQuery();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }

        return allergiesResult;
    }
```

**--------------------------------------UPDATE------------------------------------------------**

Alright this is my new logic:

```
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNewAllergy.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtReactions.Text))
       {
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNewAllergy.Text) && txtReactions.Text != null)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Please key in the Type of the allergy", "WARNING");
           }
           else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtReactions.Text) && txtNewAllergy.Text != null)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Please key in the Description  of the allergy", "WARNING");
           }
       }
       else if (txtNewAllergy.Text != null && txtReactions.Text != null)
       {
           int allergiesResult = insertAllergies();
       }
```

It seems to work but with only 1 flaw:  When I submit both texts empty, this pops out "Please key in the Type of the allergy".  How do I make it if both texts are empty, it does nothing.

Comment: `"" is != null` so it will pass use `if(txtNewAllergy.Text != null && txtNewAllergy.Text != string.Empty || txtReactions.Text != null&& txtReactions.Text != string.Empty)`

Comment: You specified that `allergiesResult` isn't doing anything. What sort of functionality do you expect from an `int`? **EDIT**: same question as @Grant, basically.

Comment: @Grant there is a code path that does nothing... (no messages whatsoever)

Comment: I'll rephrase my question: under what circumstances does `insertAllergies` return a number that's greater than 0?

Comment: int allergiesResult = insertAllergies(); ?

Answer (score 7):

If `txtNewAllergy` and `txtReactions` are `TextBox`, then it would not ever be expected for `.Text` to be `null`; you need to check for an empty non-null string instead. Try `string.IsNullOrEmpty(...)`:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNewAllergy.Text)
    || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtReactions.Text))
```

For convenience, we tend to use an extension method:

```
public static bool HasValue(this string value) {
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
}
```

Then it is:

```
if (txtNewAllergy.Text.HasValue() || txtReactions.Text.HasValue())
```

Also: note there is a code path that does nothing (see "WHAT HAPPENS HERE?"):

```
if (allergiesResult > 0)
{
    if (txtNewAllergy.Text != null || txtReactions.Text != null)
    {
        if (txtNewAllergy.Text == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please key in the Type of the allergy", "WARNING");
        }
        else if (txtReactions.Text == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please key in the Description of the allergy", "WARNING");
        }
        else
        {
            // WHAT HAPPENS HERE?
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Submitted, fool");
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Not submitted, fool");
}
```

Comment: Also, if appropriate and using .NET 4.0 or higher, consider IsNullOrWhitespace().

Comment: @bland a !String.IsNullOrEmpty and a .Length > 0 check afterwards would be better.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg You forgot the call to Trim after checking if not null. Also, IsNullOrWhitespace is optimized according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx).  And it isn't always needed to check whitespace, so only suggesting this if appropriate to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Your `INSERT` query is missing the `INTO` keyword.

Try changing `strAllergies` to this:

```
string strAllergies = @"INSERT INTO ALLERGIES (allergyType, allergyDesc, patientID)
                        VALUES (@insertType, @insertDesc, @insertPatient)";
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Is your query actually inserting anything? From what I gather, it's not.